# GetComponent returning "null" instead of null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm confused about the return value of `GetComponent` if the requested component is not attached to the object.  According to the Unity documentation, `GetComponent` should return null.  However, what appears to be happening is that `GetComponent` is returning a "null" object of the requested type, rather than the value `null`.

In this example, my game object does not have a `CircleCollider2D` attached to it.  When I set a breakpoint on the line `CircleCollider2D x = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();`, [I get this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFsZ6.jpg)

Why is the returned value not `null`?

EDIT:

[Here's a full screenshot of the code and the values in the debugger.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h40ZW.jpg)

ANOTHER EDIT:

Could it be that Unity has overloaded the `==` operator so that `GetComponent` always returns a object, but the object can have an internal "null" state which returns true when compared to `null`?  I can see the following declarations in the `UnityEngine` namespace

```
public static bool operator ==(Object x, Object y);
public static bool operator !=(Object x, Object y);
```

Comment: `However, what appears to be happening is that GetComponent is returning a "null" object of the requested type, rather than the value null.` How did you come to that conclusion? _Please show us your code - it is impossible to give you good advice without seeing the code._

Comment: The code is just `CircleCollider2D x = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();`  I have it inside of my `Awake` method.  I put a breakpoint on that line, and the screenshot is from the Locals window after stepping over that line.

Comment: What does `x.GetType()` return? _And seriously, this process becomes much easier the more code you add to your question._

Comment: `x.GetType()` returns `UnityEngine.CircleCollider2D`, which is one reason I came to the conclusion that it's returning an actual object, which has some sort of "null" internal state.  I updated my question to include a full screenshot of the code.

Comment: Is `CircleCollider2D` a struct or a class? Can you show us its source code (perhaps decompiled via https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)? Does http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1243356/getcomponent-returns-null-however-comparison-to-nu.html help?

Comment: It's a class.  It's declared as `public sealed class CircleCollider2D : Collider2D`.  My best guess is that maybe Unity is doing something to overload the `==` operator so that it can compare `null` to an object?

Comment: Yes, that answer on Unity's forum does help.  I'm glad to see this is the intended behavior and that I'm not going crazy.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like `GetComponent<T>()` doesnt return *TRUE* `null`. Instead it returns new T with default values that fires `MissingComponentException` when using any null field. `GetInstanceID()` and `GetHashCode()` work because they only use `int m_InstanceID` which is set to default 0. Not sure how `ToString()` works but it probably returns `"null"` when `m_InstanceID == 0`.

Proof:

```
void Start()
    {
        CircleCollider2D getComponent = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        CircleCollider2D empty = null;
        CircleCollider2D newCC = new CircleCollider2D();
        Debug.LogFormat("getComponent.GetInstanceID() {0}", getComponent.GetInstanceID());
        Debug.LogFormat("newCC.GetInstanceID() {0}", newCC.GetInstanceID());
        try
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("empty.GetInstanceID() {0}", empty.GetInstanceID());
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException e)
        {
            Debug.Log("empty.GetInstanceID() doesnt work, im true null");
        }
        try
        {
            string t = getComponent.name;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("getComponent fires {0} when any field is null", 
                e.ToString()));
        }
        try
        {
            string t = newCC.name;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("newCC fires {0} when any field is null",
                e.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Results:

```
getComponent.GetInstanceID() 0
newCC.GetInstanceID() 0
empty.GetInstanceID() doesnt work, im true null
getComponent fires UnityEngine.MissingComponentException
newCC fires System.NullReferenceException
```

Also:

```
getComponent.GetHashCode() = 0
getComponent.ToString() = "null"
```

Why `getComponent == null` is true? Usually it's just:

```
`getComponent.GetInstanceID() == otherComponent.GetInstanceID()`
```

In `o == null` case it's:

```
return !(
o.GetCachedPtr() != IntPtr.Zero || (!(o is MonoBehaviour) && 
!(o is ScriptableObject) &&
Object.DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist(o.GetInstanceID())));
```

So i guess object with InstanceID = 0 never exists.
Search for decompiled UnityEngine/UnityEngine/Object.cs if u want to know more.

Comment: Actually `default(IntPtr) = IntPtr.Zero` so `o.GetCachedPtr() == IntPtr.Zero`

Answer (score 2):

> Could it be that Unity has overloaded the == operator

Tldr: **Yes**.

> Why is the returned value not null?

According [Custom == operator, should we keep it?](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) :

> When a MonoBehaviour has fields, in the editor only, we do not set
>   those fields to “real null”, but to a “fake null” object.

Why? According that article, basically for two reasons:

- On Editor mode: get more contextual information on invocations, so if you have an exception you will be able to know which object was the cause.
- Every that comes from `UnityEngine.Object` are wrapped in a C# object to keep the reference to the Unity C/C++ GameEngine Object. In the editor/code we work with the C# elements but those are just a reference to the 'real' c++ objects. Now, the lifetime of those 'real' c++ objects are handled explicitly (if you `destroy` something the C++ object it will be destroyed and the allocated memory it will be freed) but the C# object will be completely destroyed when the Garbage Collector decides to free that memory. So you will have a not null C# object pointing to a null C++ object. With this *fake null* trick you will know that this specific C# object is `null` because in the C++ side it was destroyed.

---

This is also important when if you have a singleton and `if (sm_Instance == null)` is not working as expected, you can use: `if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(sm_Instance, null))` instad.

Edit: Probably this can be caused if your singleton use generics and your type constrain is `class`

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : class {
```

This will cause to use the `==` operator of a class object, even when your Singleton is a GameEngine Object. One fix for that? Instead of `class` you can use `UnityEngine.Object`, like:

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : UnityEngine.Object {
```

---

Related Thread:
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/null-check-inconsistency-c.220649/#post-1775701

---

Ps: If you go to UnityEngine.Object assembly, you will be able to see the overload:

[image: UnityEngine.Object]

Almost at the end...

[image: Overload]

Answer (score 0):

if you are still looking for solution this worked for me`

```
var component = parent.GetChild(i).GetComponent<T>();
if(component != null)
{
    if (component.ToString().Equals("null") == false)
    {
        list.Add(component);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `if (component != null) { list.Add(component); }`

Answer (score -1):

`GetComponent` is expected to return object of type 'Component`. Hence it is not expected to return "null" rather ~null` is expected value. Perhaps this strange behavior should be reported to `unity3d`,

Comment: I suspect that this "strange behavior" is actually intended.